# Location in Simulator doesn't work. I get nil latitude and nil longitude

Tags: swift, location, cllocationmanager, simulator

But when using a real device I obtain the right coordinates.

In simulator, I go to debug-Location-Custom Location or Apple but I always obtain nil values.

In real device two persons can use the app, that is, no nil values, but there's one third person that get crashes due nil values of coordinates.

In preferences, we all have activated the location services.

Comment: Post the location-code to provide more information

Comment: @user2893289 What do you mean?

Comment: You should include [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. Not all of your code, but the smallest amount to let us reproduce the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the simulator just wants to play game with your time :), so a total reset will do the trick.

However to prevent your app from crashing from the rule device or simulator, you should make sure you have complete access to the gps. so you should use didChangeAuthorizationStatus method.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
    {
        if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted
        {
           print(" Access Restricted \n")
        }
        else if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied
        {
            print(" Access Denied \n")

        }
        else if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways
        {
            self.MyLocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()  //<---- 
            print(" Access Granted \n")
        }
    }
```

As you could see when you have `AuthorizedAlways` then you want to start your gps.

Comment: I think the simulator just want to play with me, that was the first I thought. But there's one friend that crash in that exact point, but not a friend and me, just him, by the moment...